# I lock data while retrieving from SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, pdf

We have developed an application which picks up top 1 depending on a list of data on a few priority basis from a SQL database and generates a PDF document. I have installed two instances of the application in two different servers.

We are facing a problem when the two instances pick up the same data(Top 1) from DB.Could you please let me know how i can configure this issue.

Comment: And this is for what concrete database? SQL is just the query language - used by **many** database systems - and many things like locking are highly vendor-specific. Please update your tags accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest thatwhen you retrieve the data you, in a transaction, write in a `ProcessStartDate`. If that is present you know the other system has picked it up.

The reason to use a datetime instead of just a boolean is that if something crashes the process before it finishes generating your pdf it will still be in the table and you can detect stale items (eg if its over an hour old you could assume failure and clear the datetime out or something.

If you then write a `ProcessEndDate` when you have finished the process you can then keep track of what has successfully processed to account for possible crashes mid processing, etc. This is of course optional though.

At the end of the day though whatever solution you choose boils down to having some way to mark what data has been picked up by an app already.

Comment: Hi Chris,  We dont delete the data from the table..ill give you an example ...there is a row(top 1) with a unique number "1234". As given the the select query the application as to pick up this data adn process it.But if one application instance picks up this data.the other should'n pick up this data.instead it has to pick up the next TOP 1 data.

Comment: But in out scenario.both the instances are picking up the same enquiry at the same second.

Comment: Not deleting isn't a problem. Just add to the query `ProcesStartDate is not null` and that way it will automatically exclude anything where you have set the process start date (ie because its already been picked up).

Comment: Chris thanks for your inputs...But can you suggest any other alternative solution to this?

Comment: I guess you could create an intermediate that gets all of the items and then hands them out one by one in order when requested. Pretty much though you have to have either one thing getting stuff from the database or you have to leave some kind of mark for other clients to interpret. I can't think of any other options.